# References object only in access?

Tags: vba, ms-word

is the

References object

only available in Access, not in Word ?

I set the reference MS VBA Extensibility 5.3,
but

```
Dim objReference As Reference
For Each objReference In References
```

gives the error 'need  object'.

Answer (score 1):

Try qualifying `References` as follows...

```
For Each objReference In ActiveDocument.VBProject.References
```

or

```
For Each objReference In ThisDocument.VBProject.References
```

or

```
For Each objReference In Documents("Document1.docm").VBProject.References
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to add a reference to the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library" to get this working:

[image]

Comment: This is the right way:

 For Each objReference In VBE.ActiveVBProject.References